# In the Microsoft error message, "the specified module could not be found", what exactly is meant by "module" and "specified"?

Tags: windows, dll, module

Is "module" the DLL file?  Or is it something inside the DLL file?  Is "specified" the name shown in the error message?  Or how do I find out specifically what Microsoft means by "specified"?

What would happen if Microsoft changed the error message to something like "Can't find xyz.dll"?  Would that make it harder or easier to understand the error message?  I'm just trying to understand Microsoft's logic in their decisions to use words like "module" and "specified", because I noticed a huge number of questions about this error message, year after year, and nobody ever seems completely clear on exactly what it means.

Comment: The word "module" can refer to an executable or to a DLL.  The exact meaning of this error code depends on the context.

Comment: ... there *are* a few error codes whose messages include insertions, e.g. ERROR_BAD_EXE_FORMAT, "%1 is not a valid Win32 application".  There are very few applications that bother to process the insertion, however, so most of the time the user actually winds up seeing literally "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" which is not very helpful.

Comment: Would it be "can't find %1.dll"?  But wouldn't that imply Microsoft didn't know what dll was being searched for, and had to leave that up to the programmer who output the error message?

Comment: Under what context are you seeing this error message?

Comment: The context is the thousands of questions about this exact error message, posted on a lot of different internet forums for the past several years.  The issue is why the error message causes so much confusion and waste of time.  And whether a clearer error message could solve that problem.  Such as "Can't find xyz.dll" without leaving it up to the programmer to output "xyz.dll" because too many programmers don't bother.

Comment: Windows doesn't return an error message.  It returns an error code, a number.  The error you're talking about is number 126.  The application then looks up the message associated with that number in order to display it.  This design dates back to 16-bit Windows, circa 1985.  If you were designing a *new* operating system, it might make sense to return a string rather than or as well as a number, and then the string could contain contextual information such as the name of the module.  Trying to change this retroactively would not be straightforward.

Comment: Good point.  The easiest way might be for Microsoft to provide functions to convert error codes to strings.  A different one for each Microsoft function that returns an error code.  And each one would take arguments relevant to that function.  So there wouldn't be any "specified" or anything like that, but just the exact arguments provided to the error code conversion function.